# HTML5 speedtest, where to start

Tags: javascript, html

I'm looking for any useful info about where to start with HTML5 bandwidth test. I need to recreate flash based one. I'd be very greatful for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

may you can download some blobs via ajax. have a look for [this](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

Simply generate some files on your server, start the ajax request and track the time using the javascript dates.

Comment: Maybe he don't even needs to create a file (every time). Could use some big image file every time without regeneration.

Comment: yeah, thats what i meant. But for sizing matters it would be better to generate a text file. the important part is, not to gzip it while sending to client.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a flash based one, probably you can look into in as3
[as3 bandwidth calculator](https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/creating-a-bandwidth-tester-for-loading-video-in-flash-with-as3--active-8209)

Comment: That's not what the OP asked.